# How to add 'read more' link in Blog comments

Tags: comments, nodes

I created blog entry pages for different subjects in a website. Each blog page displays its comments. I need to trim the comments and add read more link. I can trim the comments, but can't able to add read more link. I can't create view for the blog pages because different blog pages needs to display differently. Any ideas? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can override comments template for your blog content type and in the template add the read more link.

In order to override the template simply copy the existing `comment.tpl.php` to your theme/templates and rename it to `comment--node-blog.tpl.php` and edit it to add the read more link.

on click of this you will be running jquery codes to toggle the comments below.